# Shortest path in 2D grid with obstacles where k obstacles can be removed

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say we have a 2D grid(size MxN) with obstacle positions marked. We want to find the shortest distance from (0,0) to (M,N). Also you can remove at most k obstacles. How can this be done using dynamic programming? 
Assume you can move in all directions.

Comment: Simple bfs keeping # of K used at every cell will give the solution.

Comment: Just found it amusing that this question got featured in LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-path-in-a-grid-with-obstacles-elimination/) after 3 years of being asked here.